# Display JSON data from API result in DOM

Tags: json, rest, dom, xmlhttprequest

Hi I have created an api request to a web application. I am able to retrieve the data successfully although when I try to display individual parts of the JSON data in the dom I get undefined. I have listed my code below.

```
//initial API call
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

request.open('GET', apiUrl + apiRequest + apiCredential + apiParameter + apiFilter, true);
request.onload = function () {
    //accessing JSON data
    data = this.response;
    if (request.status >= 200 && request.status < 400) {
            document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = data.CreatedBy;
    }
}
request.send();
```

Answer (score 1):

First and foremost, JSON is a string. And strings don't have a `CreatedBy` property.

In order to get a data structure out of that string, you must parse it:

```
//accessing JSON data
data = JSON.parse(this.response);
if (request.status >= 200 && request.status < 400) {
    document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = data.CreatedBy;
}
```

Note that `JSON.parse()` can throw an error. You might want to enclose that section in a try/catch block.

Comment: `JSON` is only a string in this particular case, not in general, which might confuse the OP

Comment: @vsync Wrong (but sadly an extremely common misconception). JSON is a string **always**.

Comment: Why do you say that? is XML also a string? I've Googled now but couldn't find a concrete information to this statement

Comment: You are not making a difference between what it **is** and what it **represents**. JSON **is** a string that **represents** an object/array/whatever. It's the *serialized form* of an object. It is not an object itself. Only after parsing the string you will get an object, and then it's not JSON anymore. JSON always is a string, and an object never is JSON.

Comment: Who knew. After a decade and a half of doing JS I randomly discover in a Stackoverflow comment a JSON definition is a *String*.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is meant snarky or not?

Comment: it's honest, I'm not one to write snarky

Comment: There is a more in-depth explanation here: http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/. It really is a super-common misconception, one that both newbees and experienced people fall for.

Comment: I think it's based in mentally "abstracting away" the parsing step when writing JS code. When one writes `var foo = {some: "value"};` into a JS file, then in that person's mind that's *"an object called `foo` with a property called `some`"*. It's not. It's a string. One that can be understood by a JS parser, which will make an AST so that the runtime can construct such an object for us. It all happens implicitly and automatic, it's easy to think it's not happening at all. The same parsing step needs to happen to JSON, only that with JSON the client code has to do it explicitly.